# Object wont follow projectile motion path

Tags: java, game-physics, projectile

Hi I was trying to work out a way to make an object move using projectile motion. When working on it myself for some reason I got an exponential movement instead of projectile. I have looked at other examples but they are kind of different since I have the coordinates of where it supposed to land and need to find the speed and the angle in which it must shoot the object.

My code:

```
public void updateDir(){

    distY = (int)( projectedY - y);
    distX = (int)(projectedX - x);
    spdY = (double)(2*distY)/(time*time);
    spdX =  (double)(distX)/time;
    dir = Math.atan(spdY/spdX);


    System.out.println("spdY: " + spdY);
    System.out.println("spdX: " + spdX);
    System.out.println("dir: " + Math.toDegrees(dir));
}


public void move() {
    x +=   (spd*Math.cos(dir));
    y -=  (spd * Math.sin(dir));
}
```

projectedY and projectedX are the coordinates that it should land on.

So any reason why it's not moving in a projectile motion path, but instead going in an exponential path?

Comment: What is spd in the move() method? Where do you change the y-velocity according to gravity and time?

Comment: The spd in the move() is basically the spd of the movement it doesn't change. The y velocity is spdY, so it changes based off the distance. The thing is I wasn't really sure what to put for gravity since there is none. the spdY I guess is calculating the gravity speed.

Answer (score 0):

These are the (Newtonian) equations for calculating the coordinates of an object starting with velocity v0, at angle theta, subject to gravity g after time t:

**x = v0 * t * cos(theta)**

**y = v0 * t * sin(theta) - (gt^2)/2**

These formulas can be expanded to include x0 and y0, which would be starting positions, and also t could be changed to to include starting time that isn't 0, such that you could find a relatively difference from 1st second to 1.5 second in the path. These have been omitted.

Every time you need to draw the object, you can use those formulas to calculate the position, given that someone (a piece of code) keeps track of the time (very important in games).

Example piece of code (not complete and pseudocode aswell):

```
class GUI {
    startProjectile() {
        model.startProjectile();
    }    

    paint() {
        Location l = model.getLocationOfProjectile();
        graphics.draw(projectile, l);
    }
}

class Model {
    startProjectile() {
        long projectileStartTime = System.currenttimemillis();
    }

    Location getLocationOfProjectile() {
        long timeInAir = System.currentTimemillis() - projectileStartTime;
        // Insert formulas for calculating the x and y coordinates based on the time, initial velocity and gravity
    }
}
```

The most important thing you should note from the above, is that you do not need to calculate the x and y velocities directly, unless you need them for other stuff of course. You can, based on the constants for your world, and the time, calculate the x and y position directly and simply draw it there.

You need to account for collision, too, but I guess you'll get to that issue later. :)

Comment: So I would be using the two top equations to calculate where the object goes (the equation in the move())? Also how would I find the angle? The reason I was looking for the x,y vel. was to find the angle it would take to make it to the point

Comment: You can substitute v0*sin(theta) and v0*cos(theta) with y-vel and x-vel respectively. In your "move()" method right now, you're adding a bit of displacement to the last known position, in order to get the new one. That's intuitively an OK way of doing it. What I was trying to convey is that you don't have to do this. You can calculate the absolute position from scratch each time with no overhead in calculations.

Comment: Okay I'll try and implement it in and see what happens. Thank you.